# Draw path in MKMapView using Google Map

Tags: ios, iphone

I implement MKMapView in my application to draw a path between two place,i found all lat long between two point using google map API but it shows the path through road.
My problem is that i want to show the path in building,

For example:
I want to draw path between the gate1 to gate 2 of Building, i pass the "to and from" lat-long in to the google MAP API, it shows the path through road so it shows the wrong distance.

I tried the indoor map also but it works only in register buildings.

Comment: It is not possible man

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Building to building is not possible.No other way.

Comment: @ParthMehta try with mode=walking . find some on google api for get walking direction . should you got your route as per your requiremnt .

Comment: @Darshan thank you for reply but I tried with this mode also but did not get the perfect route as per my requirenment.

Comment: @ParthMehta Then may be not possible this kind of thing.